# Repeating linear gradient breaks in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, linear-gradients

Having a weird problem with repeating-linear-gradient in Safari. Works fine in Chrome, but for some reason Safari spits out a jumbled mess. There doesn't even appear to be a repeating pattern to what it's doing wrong.

**CSS**:

```
div{
    background-image: 
        repeating-linear-gradient( 
            to bottom, 
            #f1f1f2, #f1f1f2 1px, 
            #ffffff 1px, #ffffff 30px, 
            #f1f1f2 30px, #f1f1f2 31px, 
            #ffffff 31px, #ffffff 59px, 
            #f1f1f2 59px, #f1f1f2 61px, 
            #ffffff 61px
        );
}
```

All other settings are default.

Here's what Safari returns:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: try increase thickness http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwxBwy or contrast http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWzZyx or look at  the graphic settings ...

Comment: Still broken in Safari 11, it can't render small values properly...